# What's the origin of the word "Wizard" in software terms?

Tags: software, words

I've been thinking about this for a while. In software you have bugs. From what I know this naming is used because someone had a problem once getting hardware to work due to an actual living bug in the system.

But where does the word "Wizard"come from in software context?

I doubt someone had an actual wizard install something on their system once and decided to call it that :P

Comment: AFAIR, the term was introduced by MS with Windows 95 and later generalised with Office 97 (see MSDN of this bygone era).

Comment: This question is language-specific. And it's a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/65728/26446) at English.SE